# Ошибка в выполнении задачи из курса по Python разработке

Tags: python

> Пользователь придумывает пароль и вводит его с клавиатуры. Пароль должен состоять более чем из 8 символов, содержать как минимум по одной прописной и заглавной букве.

Пробовала использовать цикл while, условие, но максимум, чего добилась - проверка пароля на кол-во символов.

```
password = input("Create a password: \n")


while len(password) <= 8 or password.islower() < 1 or password.isupper() < 1:
    
    print("Your password isn't acceptable. Create a new password: \n")

else:

    print("You created a safe password")
```

Понимаю, что вопрос банальный, а код написан с глупыми ошибками. Питон изучаю совсем недолго, а наставник на курсе не может нормально объяснить.

Comment: Поместите здесь ваше решение, укажите, что мешает решить полностью. Полагаю, вопрос на регулярку, что-то о ней у вас ни слова.

Comment: @Сергей учебное задание на регулярку .. сомнительно )

Comment: Сто раз тут подобные вопросы задавались и отвечались, поиск работает )

Comment: @Kromster, почему? У меня были на Stepic (часть 3.2 в <https://stepik.org/course/512/syllabus>). Я их даже сделал, хотел 100% сертификат иметь (но не понравились регулярные выражения мне). А разве здесь регулярное выражение не самым эффективным будет?

Comment: @Сергей мне кажется, что регулярка для изучающего питон (а не регулярки) будет магическим набором абракадабр, а не практической задачей на улучшение понимания основ программирования и/или языка. Что касается эффективности - это спорный вопрос, т.к. метрики могут быть разными, и не всегда это минимизация LOC.

Comment: Кстати, обратите внимание, как переименовал ваш вопрос. Показывает, что вам помощь с ошибкой нужна, а не сделать за вас задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле ошибки не настолько уж глупые, а идея была верная:-)
Но вам нужно, чтобы `password.islower()` или `password.isupper()` выдавали `True`, для невыполнения условия безопасного пароля. Т.е. вам надо не `<1` было ставить, а `==1` (эквивалент `True`). А по правилам языка можно для `True` и ничего не ставить (см. ниже).

И цикл не очень удачно был организован, зациклится при неправильном пароле.
Ниже более классическая организация (работающая). Или ваш вариант с добавленным `password = input()` тоже подойдет.

```
while True:
    password = input("Create a password: \n")
    if len(password) <= 8 or password.islower() or password.isupper():
        print("Your password isn't acceptable.")
    else:
        print("You created a safe password")
        break
```